# Determine the values ​of the $m$ parameter so that the origin is stable in the sense of Liapunov.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Determine the values ​​of the $m$ parameter so that the origin is stable in the sense of Liapunov.

$$\dot{x}=\begin{pmatrix}-(m+1)& 0 & 2(m+1)\\0 & -2 & 0\\-(m+1) & 0 & 2(m+1)\end{pmatrix}x$$

The first thing I have tried is to verify that zero is a point of equilibrium and clearly it is, now what follows is to see that the matrix above has all the eigenvalues ​​with a negative real part, this is equivalent to the definition of stability in the sense of Liapunov? Could someone help me understand this and tell me if I'm confused? Thank you very much.

**Let $\phi_t$ denote the flow of the differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x)$ defined
for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. An equilibrium point $x_o$ of $\dot{x}=f(x)$ is stable if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in N_{\delta}(x_0)$ and $t > 0$ we have $\phi_t (x)\in N_{\epsilon}(x_0)$**

Comment: Do you mean $\phi_t(x) \in N_\epsilon(x_0)$ in the last line?

Comment: @RobertLewis yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system is a LTI system $\dot x=Ax$,
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-(m+1)&0&2(m+1)\\
0&-2&0\\
-(m+1)&0&2(m+1)\\
\end{array}\right).
$$
A LTI system is

- asymptotically stable if and only if 
  all the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part;
- stable (but not asymptotically stable) if and only if 
  all the eigenvalues have non positive real part and the eigenvalues with 
  zero real part have corresponding Jordan blocks of size $1$;
- unstable if and only if there exists at least one eigenvalue with 
  positive real part or a Jordan block of size $>1$ corresponding to an eigenvalue with 
  zero real part

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-2$, $0$ and $m+1$, thus, if $m>-1$ then the system is unstable. If $m<-1$ then $A$ is diagonalizable (as it has distinct eigenvalues), therefore, all of its Jordan blocks are of size 1 and the system is stable (but not asymptotically stable).  In the case when $m=-1$
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0&0&0\\
0&-2&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right);
$$
it is already in Jordan normal form and  all of its Jordan blocks are also of size 1.

Comment: What is the difference in stability that one knows with stability in the sense of Liapunov?

Comment: @user402543 There is no difference, it is the same thing

Comment: Ahhh ok, could you help me with other exercises?

Comment: @user402543 I can't promise this :)